# Error after using a 2nd docker-compose file to run a container that was previously setup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two docker-compose.yml files, one to setup the container and the other for any subsequent run of the container:

**docker-compose.setup.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:11.1"
    env_file:
      - ./volumes/postgres_config/env_file
    networks:
      - db_nw

  pyramid_app:
    image: image_from_dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./volumes/postgres_config/env_file
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/pyramid_app:/app/src
    image: image_from_dockerfile
    working_dir: /app
    expose:
      - 6543
    command: >
      sh -c "/app/venv/bin/pip install -r /app/src/requirements.pip &&
          /app/venv/bin/pip install -e '/app/src[testing]' &&
          /app/venv/bin/pserve /app/src/development.ini --reload"
    networks:
    - db_nw
    - web_nw
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13.5
    ports:
    - "6543:80"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nginx_config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
    - web_nw
    depends_on:
      - pyramid_app

networks:
  db_nw:
    driver: bridge
  web_nw:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  conf.d:
  src:
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:11.1"
    env_file:
      - ./volumes/postgres_config/env_file
    networks:
      - db_nw

  pyramid_app:
    image: image_from_dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./volumes/postgres_config/env_file
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/pyramid_app:/app/src
    image: image_from_dockerfile
    working_dir: /app
    expose:
      - 6543
    command: /app/venv/bin/pserve /app/src/development.ini --reload
    networks:
    - db_nw
    - web_nw
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13.5
    ports:
    - "6543:80"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nginx_config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
    - web_nw
    depends_on:
      - pyramid_app

networks:
  db_nw:
    driver: bridge
  web_nw:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  conf.d:
  src:
```

The docker-compose.setup.yml runs fine and starts my webapp, but I'm getting a "no such file or dir" error anytime I try to run the subsequent docker-compose.yml file:

```
PS C:\Users\Raj\Projects\github_example> docker-compose up
Starting 81f076500a73_github_example_db_1 ... done
Recreating bc2fafc2039d_github_example_pyramid_app_1 ... error

ERROR: for bc2fafc2039d_github_example_pyramid_app_1  Cannot start service pyramid_app: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/app/venv/bin/pserve\": stat /app/venv/bin/pserve: no such file or directory": unknown

ERROR: for pyramid_app  Cannot start service pyramid_app: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/app/venv/bin/pserve\": stat /app/venv/bin/pserve: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Also, this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
MAINTAINER Raj &amp;lt;raj@fake.email&amp;gt;

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get -yqq update && apt-get install -yqq python3 python3-dev python3-pip python3-venv

RUN mkdir -p /app/venv
RUN python3 -m venv /app/venv
RUN ls /app/venv

RUN /app/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

WORKDIR /app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard use of the Docker tools is to install your application in the Dockerfile.  You wouldn't run a separate Docker Compose sequence to build the application; all of the "build" steps would go in the `docker build` sequence.  Your Dockerfile could look like:

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install system-level dependencies
RUN apt-get -yqq update \
 && apt-get install -yqq python3 python3-dev python3-pip \
 && pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

# Install Python dependencies (in the Docker-isolated Python)
WORKDIR /app/src
COPY pyramid_app/requirements.pip .
RUN pip install -r requirements.pip

# Install the application proper
COPY pyramid_app/ ./
RUN pip install -e '.[testing]'

# Metadata to say how to run the application
EXPOSE 6543
CMD pserve ./development.ini --reload
```

Now that all of that setup information, the application source, and the default command are in the Docker image proper, you can just run it, without any special run-time setup:

```
version: '3'
services:
  pyramid_app:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - ./volumes/postgres_config/env_file
```

I would remove the special segregated network setup and just use the single default network Docker Compose creates for you.  I wouldn't try to force Docker to do all of its work in host-system directories.  You don't need `networks:`, `volumes:`; `expose:` and `working_dir:` come from the Dockerfile; and `depends_on:` mostly isn't useful (nor for that matter is `expose:`).

What's actually going on in your proposed setup is that your Dockerfile creates an empty Python virtual environment in the image; the first `docker-compose.yml` file creates a container from that image, installs software in the virtual environment *in the container*, then discards the container and its installed software; and then the second `docker-compose.yml` file starts up a second container from the image with an empty virtual environment.

Comment: I was using docker-compose specifically because it allows for volumes. I don't want to rebuild the Dockerfile everytime I make changes to the webapp's source code. Also, I was reading that despite using Docker, a venv is useful for putting scripts on the path env.

Comment: Also, why separate the copying of pyramid_app/requirements.pip and pyramid_app in its entirety? Why not just do it once and then do the requirements and setup.py installations?

Comment: That avoids re-running `pip install -r` if your requirements list hasn't changed.

Comment: Thanks David, could you kindly address the previous comment as well?

Comment: For the development I do, I find it works extremely well to do purely local development and totally ignore Docker until my application basically works (ideally including a reasonable `pytest` suite or similar), and only then pull out Docker.  With a good local development environment, having to repeat `docker build` only at deploy time isn't a significant impediment.  You don't need a magic virtualenv bin directory to put extra scripts in your container, just use `/usr/local/bin` (or `.`).

Comment: If you're not using docker during development then you are installing the same system and pip packages to your host machine?

Comment: That's what the requirements list in `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` are for.

Comment: I am going to stick with my development environment workflow but thank you for explaining how the `venv` directory was getting lost.